# Create and show a label after running java application

Tags: java, swing

I have been working on a problem for 2 days and it's going to be a headache for me!
I use swing to create the GUI for my app. I want to add a label to my panel after running the code by clicking on the button, but I can't. Please help me to solve this problem.
Much of this code is auto-generated by swing and it's not code I wrote.

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class RandomWordGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/** Creates new form RandomWordGUI */
public RandomWordGUI() {
    initComponents();
}


/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(155, 155, 155)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(172, 172, 172)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)))
            .addContainerGap(172, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(70, 70, 70)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(91, 91, 91))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(186, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 114, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    JLabel jLabel2 = new JLabel();
    jLabel2.setText("this is a label");
    this.jPanel1.add(jLabel2);
    this.jPanel1.repaint();
    this.jPanel1.revalidate();


}                                        

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {


        public void run() {
            new RandomWordGUI().setVisible(true);


        }
        RandomWordGUI randWord=new RandomWordGUI();



    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying adding to add to a panel using `GroupLayout`. Adding dynamically to that would be quite tricky (if possible), and I do not recommend that. I recommend adding a helper `JPanel` to the pane, and adding any new components to that helper panel.

EDIT:

To clear the solution that was used: a helper `JPanel` was added using the form editor (`jPanel3` in the code below). The form designer defaults to using `GroupLayout` for the added panel too, which would lead to the same problem that was to be solved in the first place, so the layout manager of the helper panel was changed to `FlowLayout`. The action code ends up being as simple as:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JLabel jLabel2 = new JLabel();
    jLabel2.setText("this is a label");
    this.jPanel3.add(jLabel2);
    this.jPanel3.revalidate();
}
```

Comment: I added a panel manually and added the label to it. Then added the panel to frame (by `this.getContentPane().add(jPanel2)` ) ,but it didn't work.

Comment: @user2686824 I meant that add a JPanel to the window in the same place as you add everything else. It then has no contents and defaults to zero size. Then you can add any components that you want to that, originally invisible, panel.

Comment: Alternatively, if it's only one component that you just sometimes want to show. Just put it in the window and call `setVisible(false)` on it. And just call `setVisible(true)` once you want to show it.

Comment: No I want add multiple component to panel. Dear Kiheru I defined a new panel and added it to frame and so on, but it didn't work, believe me... If I am wrong please say your way with more details please...

Comment: @user2686824 Okay, then use the helper panel approach. Create the helper in the form designer like you have done for rest of the window. And do `panel2.add(jlabel2)` in the action listener. (Oh, and check that the form designer does not do something stupid like setting the layout manager of the helper panel; you should use something else than GroupLayout there. JPanels use FLowLayout by default, which may or may not be what you want).

Comment: Dear kiheru do you let me send my edited code for you to see it ? (Because I don't want waste your time...I think these question are so silly for you...)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35539/discussion-between-kiheru-and-user2686824)

Comment: @kiheru we can do this without using helper panel..Plz check my answer.Its pain if coding manually ... but not impossible :D

Answer (score 1):

I entered another Panel in my Window- jPanel3- and added jLabel2 to it... then added this code in content of ActionEvent
`jPanel3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());`

and every thing became ok... :)

Thanks to my dear friend , ***@Kiheru*** for his help and guidance.

Comment: You still need to call `jPanel3.revalidate()` after adding a new `JLabel` to this already visible `JPanel`. I doubt, without the use of the same, you be able to get consistent results.

Comment: @nlcE yes,obviously we should call revalidate() after any component adding.

Answer (score 0):

Well finally my friend Here is the code. What we need to is

- as we are adding the label dynamically we need to set the layout again.
- so we need to copy pase the layout created by the IDE
- manually enter in both horizontal and vertical groups

> **.addComponent(jLabel2)**
>
> **.addGap()**

- your positioning is at the bottom of the screen so i advice you just changed the position for better view
- plz take care of the gaps and positioning..
- just paste the code in actionPerformed function remaing is same

  ```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

  JLabel jLabel2 = new JLabel();
  jLabel2.setText("this is a label");
  javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
  jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
  jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
      jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
      .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
          .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
              .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                  .addGap(155, 155, 155)
                  .addComponent(jButton1))
              .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                  .addGap(172, 172, 172)
                  .addComponent(jLabel2)
                  .addGap(1,1,1)
                  .addComponent(jLabel1)))
          .addContainerGap(172, Short.MAX_VALUE))
  );
  jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
      jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
      .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
          .addGap(70, 70, 70)
          .addComponent(jLabel1)
          ***.addGap(1,1,1)
          .addComponent(jLabel2)***
          .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
          .addComponent(jButton1)
          .addGap(91, 91, 91))
  );

  this.jPanel1.repaint();
  this.jPanel1.revalidate();
  ```

  `}`