# Why don't I see the image or the button?

Tags: java, image, swing, netbeans, jbutton

I am trying to add a button over the image. But neither see the button nor the image. Why is that ? I am calling this method from the constructor just after the `initComponents` method is called by the IDE.

```
public void initD() {
    try {
        BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication1\\src\\javaapplication1\\meaning.JPG"));
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
        JButton b = new JButton("Press me");
        jPanel1.add(picLabel);
        jPanel1.add(b);
        System.out.println("last statement");
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I only see the frame as an output.

Comment: What layout manager are you using?  Did you know the `JButton` has icon support?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @MadProgrammer The default used by IDE. I have just added this method. I have to add many buttons over the image.

Comment: If the default by IDE is `GroupLayout` then adding to it dynamically is tricky. Use a helper panel with a different layout manager (somewhat similar situation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258482/create-and-show-a-label-after-running-java-application/18258621#18258621)).

Comment: @kiheru I didn't get that. Can you explain as what do I need to do through an answer

Comment: `GroupLayout` requires adding the components to the *layout*, and in a rather complicated way. Change the layout manager of `jPanel1` to something more appropriate (or use a helper panel if `jPanel1` has some other contents that have been placed using the IDE).

Comment: @saplingPro : Please have a look at this answer for [how to load an Image to the Project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

I dont know which layout you are using, however you should implement `button.setIcon();` like this;

```
public void initD() {
    JButton button = new JButton("Press me");
    try {
        BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication1\\src\\javaapplication1\\meaning.JPG"));
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));

        button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(myPicture));

        System.out.println("last statement");
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In addition you may need to consider resource of your image maybe this implemantation can be helpfull ;

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/meaning.JPG")));
```

Comment: I want buttons over image..not image over a button

Comment: @saplingPro : Please have a look at this answer, regarding [adding background image](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11428289/1057230), hope it might be able to help you. Though the last link in the comments to your question, is a better approach, to draw the image on the `JPanel` and add components to it, instead of putting components on the `JLabel`.